# Is ~150 queries per second reasonable on a 25M mongo corpus?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a 24 hour batch job where I need to lookup and update approximately 25M mongo records via a compound index.  I have one 16 cpu box feeding a mongo query controller that feeds 4 shards.  mongostat is showing ~150 queries/sec on the query controller.  At my query rate, I'll never hit 24 hours.  Before digging further and trying new things, I just wanted to do a reality check, are my numbers reasonable or is something off here?  Thanks for any help.

Kevin

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing your document structure and your queries and knowing more about your hardware specs. But even with all that info you won't get more than a very rough guesstimate. You have to try for yourself.

Comment: @Philipp's Observation is absolutely correct. Depending on what you do with the data, 150q/s can be lightning fast or extremely slow. We need to see the data and the operations to judge that. Oh, and the indices and RAM size will be necessary information, too. Furthermore, I suggest posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com, since SO is aimed at programming questions.

Comment: How many threads? What kind of updates are you doing?

Comment: 32 processes just doing find and update existing records, just updating a couple of floating points. But I'm pretty sure the finds are the bottleneck because the records have to be found to be updated. Fwiw 32 or 64 or 128 processes make no difference on the client machine. I'm almost certain I'm not cpu or memory or network bound. My hunch is that the single query controller is serially limited by the return time from the shards. Query controller and shards are all well below 10% cpu usage.